# How to create page with slider and page indicator in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, slider

I am new in xamarin forms, I want to develop a page with image sliding and page indicator , how can I do this.

Please help me, am stuck on this.....

[image]

The page looks like the above image, I have no idea..

Comment: I f any one know the answer please give me a reply

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a `CarouselView`

There are many ways to do this however you are going to have to look at third party solutions as i dont think there is a native solution anymore. Formally known as a `CarouselPage`

There are plenty of examples on the internet, please take a look at some of these

- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103211/carousel-view-in-xamarin-forms
- https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/
- https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-xamarin-forms/
- https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView
- https://15mgm15.ghost.io/2017/01/29/xamarin-forms-carousel-view-tutorial/

Comment: Not carousel view ,I want to create a page like the above image